# How to yield until GetResponseStream is finished?

Tags: c#, multithreading, httpwebrequest

I'm using this code (below) to read a web response, however, I'm getting an incomplete response. If I `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);`, right after I run `GetResponseStream();` however, I get the complete response.

```
HttpWebRequest http = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url))
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) http.GetResponse();
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    string response = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

How can I yield until it has completed?

Comment: How do you determine you get an incomplete response? From what site are you reading? Is it possible they implement some kind of rate limiting?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you show; it should retrieve the entire response. "It works for me."

Comment: You should use the word "block" here, since "yield" implies returning execution contest to the caller